# MouseLeftButtonUp does not fire all the time in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mouseleftbuttonup

In my app there is a canvas with a small image (not taking up entire space of canvas). 
when user clicks on image and drags inside the canvas, it traces the path with a black line. Till here everything works. Now, I want the path to be deleted as soon as the user releases the hold on the mouse. I am using `MouseLeftButtonUp` on the `canvas` to detect the mouse release. Now problem is this is working randomly. sometimes it fires and sometimes it does not. Kindly help.

XAML:

```
 <Canvas Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Center"  Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="canvas1" VerticalAlignment="Center" Background="Aqua"  Width="400">
 <Image Canvas.ZIndex="30" Canvas.Left="10" Canvas.Top="10" Height="20" Name="dot1" Stretch="Uniform" Width="20" Source="/BoxIt;component/Images/dot.png" MouseLeftButtonDown="dot_MouseLeftButtonDown" />
 </Canvas>
```

C#:

```
 this.canvas1.MouseMove += new MouseEventHandler(canvas1_MouseMove);
 this.canvas1.MouseLeftButtonUp += new MouseButtonEventHandler(canvas1_MouseLeftButtonUp);
```

Eventhandler in C# :

```
 void canvas1_MouseLeftButtonUp(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
       // code to delete the path
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Windows Phone we are advised to use the [Tap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.tap%28v=vs.95%29.aspx), [Hold](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.hold%28v=vs.95%29) and Manipulation* methods instead of the Mouse related events.

Please read [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff426933%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) for more information.